# multiuser chat application on adhoc network in java

Tags: java, sockets, adhoc

I'm working on a multiuser chatting application on adhoc network, and one of its features is to allow the user to chat with more than one friend at the same time.
Can anybody tell me when to start? Can i use socket programming for this... Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You _need_ to use Sockets for this.

Comment: Check out this example as a starting point: https://github.com/jk1/LocalAreaChat

Comment: Your question is very broad. Maybe you could elaborate on what you already have and what you are planning to do. Then list a couple of specific questions like: "I want to write the application in Java. Do I need to program the sockets myself?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to implement a publisher subscriber model.Basically have each of your users implement an interface

```
interface chatWithUser {
   public String getMessage();

   public List<ChatWithUser> getFriends();
}
```

All these users are subscribers to the chat feature. Now we will have a publisher which would have a list of subscribers. Now when a request for chat comes from a users socket the publisher will check the list of users

```
public class PublishChattMessage
{
   List<chatWithUser> userChatList;

   public void setUpChat(ChatUser mainUser )
  {
     for(ChatWithUser user:userChatList)
     {
         List<ChatUser> userList = user.getFriends()
        // set up connections with all friends
     }
  } 

  /**
   *  Method to chat between two users. u
   **/
  public void chat(ChatUser userOne,ChatUser user2)
  {

  }
}
```

Once the connection is set up with all friends then call the chat method and display the messages

Comment: Chat application on adhoc network, many things needs to be considered like dynamic topology,mobility,routing protocols.

Comment: The assumption here is that the the chat method handles all that

Comment: I need some routing protocol to forward packets from one adhoc network to another. There is jAdhoc which is an implementation of AODV protocol in Adhoc network. Do anybody has any idea that how can i use this for my project.