# Java Chat: from single user to multiuser. (serversocket and mysql involved)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, chat

I have been trying to get my existing chat class for the messages to be visible by multiple users but I do not seem to know how to do it.

```
public class user 



{

        JFrame chatWindow = null;
        JButton sendButton = null;
        JTextField message = null;  
        JTextArea chatArea = null;
        JPanel chatArea_Container = null;
        JPanel sendButton_Container = null;
        JScrollPane Scroll = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        PrintWriter writer = null;

        JButton login;
        JTextField username;
        JTextField password;
        JPanel login_Container = null;

        public user(){
            userGUI();
        }
        public void userGUI(){

            chatWindow= new JFrame ("Client");
            username = new JTextField ("");
            password = new JTextField ("");
            login = new JButton ("login");
            sendButton = new JButton ("Send");
            message = new JTextField (4);

            chatArea = new JTextArea (10,12);
            Scroll = new JScrollPane(chatArea);
            chatArea_Container = new JPanel();
            chatArea_Container.setLayout (new GridLayout (1,1));
            chatArea_Container.add(Scroll);

            login_Container = new JPanel();
            login_Container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
            login_Container.add(username);
            login_Container.add(password);
            login_Container.add(login);

            sendButton_Container = new JPanel();
            sendButton_Container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
            sendButton_Container.add(message);
            sendButton_Container.add(sendButton);

            chatWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            chatWindow.add(chatArea_Container,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            chatWindow.add(sendButton_Container,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            chatWindow.add(login_Container,BorderLayout.NORTH);

            chatWindow.setSize(600, 350);   
            chatWindow.setVisible(true);
            chatWindow.setResizable(false);
            chatWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);






            Thread main = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        socket = new Socket ("localhost", 9000);
                        read();
                        write();
                        }
                    catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
                    main.start();
        }

        public void read(){
            Thread read_Thread = new Thread (new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));
                        while (true){
                            String messageReceived = reader.readLine();
                            chatArea.append("Server says: "+messageReceived+"\n");
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            read_Thread.start();
        }

        public void write(){
            Thread writeThread = new Thread (new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{ 
                        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
                            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                                String sending_message = message.getText();
                                writer.println(sending_message);
                                message.setText("");
                            }
                        });
                    }catch (Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } 

                }
            });
            writeThread.start();
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new user();
    }
    public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

My server class is pretty much equal to this one but changing from socket to serversocket.

```
{

        JFrame chatWindow = null;
        JButton sendButton = null;
        JTextField message = null;
        JTextArea chatArea = null;
        JPanel chatArea_Container = null;
        JPanel sendButton_Container = null;
        JScrollPane Scroll = null;
        ServerSocket server = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        JButton login;
        JTextField username;
        JTextField password;
        JPanel login_Container = null;


        public server(){
            serverGUI();
        }
        public void serverGUI(){

            chatWindow= new JFrame ("Server");
            username = new JTextField ("");
            password = new JTextField ("");
            login = new JButton ("login");
            login.addActionListener(this);

            sendButton = new JButton ("Send");
            message = new JTextField (4);

            chatArea = new JTextArea (10,12);
            Scroll = new JScrollPane(chatArea);
            chatArea_Container = new JPanel();
            chatArea_Container.setLayout (new GridLayout (1,1));
            chatArea_Container.add(Scroll);

            login_Container = new JPanel();
            login_Container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
            login_Container.add(username);
            login_Container.add(password);
            login_Container.add(login);

            sendButton_Container = new JPanel();
            sendButton_Container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
            sendButton_Container.add(message);
            sendButton_Container.add(sendButton);


            chatWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            chatWindow.add(chatArea_Container,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            chatWindow.add(sendButton_Container,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            chatWindow.add(login_Container,BorderLayout.NORTH);

            chatWindow.setSize(600, 350);   
            chatWindow.setVisible(true);
            chatWindow.setResizable(false);
            chatWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            Thread main = new Thread (new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                    server = new ServerSocket(9000);
                        while(true){
                            socket = server.accept();
                            read();
                            write();
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            });
            main.start();
        }



        public void read(){
            Thread read_Thread = new Thread (new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));
                        while (true){
                            String messageReceived = reader.readLine();
                            chatArea.append("User says: "+messageReceived+"\n");
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            read_Thread.start();
        }

        public void write(){
            Thread writeThread = new Thread (new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{ 
                        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
                            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                                String sending_message = message.getText();
                                writer.println(sending_message);
                                message.setText("");
                            }
                        });
                    }catch (Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } 

                }
            });
            writeThread.start();
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            new server();

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I would need to add a way to get the messages to be seen by multiple users but I do not know how to make this.

How would you sort this out? I was looking at this: [multiuser chat application on adhoc network in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080636/multiuser-chat-application-on-adhoc-network-in-java)

Do I basically need to modify the server class to have no read and write methods and just open two user windows?

Comment: First off, you're violating the single thread rules of Swing, Swing is NOT thread safe and you should only ever update the UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution

Comment: As to your question, your server needs to keep track of all the active client connections.  Each time a message is sent to the server, the server needs to re-broadcast this to all the other clients

Comment: Thank you MadPRogrammer.

Comment: I'm still a beginner and I would need a little bit more information about the rebroadcasting you are meaning. Can you elaborate it in a small pseudocode snippet?